# google-api-ruby-client not finding classes PKCS12 & JWTAsserter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-api-ruby-client

I am receiving the following errors with the google-api-ruby-client:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Google::APIClient::PKCS12 
NameError: uninitialized constant Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter
```

Here is a synopsis of my code:

```
require 'google/api_client'

class Commissions::GoogleAffiliateNetwork < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.path_to_key_file
    Rails.root + 'config/xxx-privatekey.p12'
  end

  def self.passphrase
    'supersecretphrase'
  end

  def self.service_email
    '42@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
  end

  def api_auth_uri
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gan'
  end

  def self.make_request(opts = {})
    key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(path_to_key_file, passphrase)
    asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(service_email, api_auth_uri, key)

    api_client = Google::APIClient.new
    api_client.authorization = asserter.authorize()
  end

end
```

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'google-api-client'
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Which version of the gem are you using? Can you check that you're on 0.4.4?

Comment: Yup, that was the problem - for some reason 0.3.0 was installed. Upon upgrading to 0.4.4 the problem was solved! Thanks much.

Comment: @SteveBazyl Gotta put these as answers man. :-)